# Only update the deleted row on a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a commenting system in my application and I want to make a trigger that activates on delete of a Comment. I want the trigger to change the Comment text to [Deleted]. Here's what I have so far, how do I make sure it only affects the row that would have been deleted?

```
    Create trigger tr_Comment_On_Delete on Comment
Instead of delete
AS
begin
    update Comment
    SET CommentText = '[Deleted]'

end
```

Comment: And why not just do it in the first place instead of deleting it and using a trigger afterwards?

Comment: What you're looking for can be found in documentation for SQL Server. You need to obtain your values from a table called `deleted`

Comment: @juergend I don't want to delete the comment I want to keep it but turn the text of the comment to '[Deleted]'

Comment: KamilG I know the deleted table exists but I can't seem to find a clear example on it.

Comment: Posted my answer to clarify it for you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a primary key on column `id` in your `Comment` table, you could refer to `deleted` table to get the specific row on which you want to act (perform an update).

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Comment_On_Delete on Comment
INSTEAD OF delete
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE Comment
  SET CommentText = '[Deleted]'
  FROM Comment
  JOIN deleted d ON Comment.id = d.id
END
```

*tested on SQL Server 2014 EE*

---

Full test scenario (delete comment with `id = 2`):

```
create table Comment(id int, CommentText text);
insert into Comment values (1, 'asd'), (2, 'bcf');
select * from comment;
go

CREATE TRIGGER tr_Comment_On_Delete on Comment
INSTEAD OF delete
AS
begin
  UPDATE Comment
  SET CommentText = '[Deleted]'
  FROM Comment
  JOIN deleted d ON Comment.id = d.id

end
go

delete from comment where id = 2;
select * from comment;
```